# Reasoning about rational numbers

Tags: equation-solving, rationals, memberq

If $x$ is a positive rational number, then of course so is $2 x$.

How can we make *Mathematica* yield this result?

The obvious approach doesn't work:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] PositiveRationals,
 MemberQ[2 x, PositiveRationals]]
```

I've tried `Reduce` and so on, without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Assuming[Element[x, PositiveRationals], Simplify@Element[2*x, PositiveRationals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[Element[x, PositiveRationals], Simplify@Element[Pi*x, PositiveRationals]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Help on [Element](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) says

[image]

Comment: Oh gosh... that simple.  Thanks.  ($+1, \checkmark$)